# Before - After survey testing with a control group, how to analyse

Tags: intervention-analysis

**Sample size in intervention area n=800**

For the purpose of measuring progress on the proportion of families having access to a service (yes/no variable) by households in eight intervention villages, a household survey was held some years ago in which 100 households were randomly selected providing an n=800 for the baseline in the intervention villages.

**Sample size in control area n=400**

To control for the proportion of households who obtained access to a service without an intervention we selected eight similar towns and had 50 households randomly selected for the same household survey providing n=400 for the baseline in the control villages.

**Endline data collection**

We will redo these household surveys in the same villages maintaining the same sample sizes mentioned above. The household will be selected randomly as it is impossible to identify the same household for the endline as were selected in the baseline, so the data will **not** be paired.

**Analytical objective**

Our aim is to determine the change in the proportion of household getting access to a service in percentage points in the intervention area corrected for the change of the proportion of households getting access in the control villages without this intervention.
We also want to determine if this change is considered statistically significant.

**We have:**

... trolled the internet thinking it would provide a solution but after finding a wide variety of tests named after eminent statisticians and contradicting opinions, we got lost and were wondering what the best test would be to determine this, and in particular how to do it.

**What we think we need to do**

We think we need to do an unpaired T-test but do not know how to include the control data into the analysis. All unpaired T-test examples we found,  do not use any control group data.

We know we need to weight the data to get absolute access figures in (%) as each village is different in size, but were told that weighting is not required for doing the significance testing and are confused about that.

> We know the principle is:
>
> [proportion(endline, intervention) - proportion(baseline, intervention)] -
>   [proportion(endline, controle) - proportion(baseline, controle)]

but we do not know how to do this with the different data sets.

**Our request ...**

Is there anybody that can point us in the right direction for example to a worked out example in a spreadsheet or with R which explains to us what to do. We are willing practitioners with some basic understanding of stats but would appreciate a simple explanation.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.